# how to build a Backbone menu loaded from a JSON file?

Tags: json, backbone.js

I'm newbie in Backbone.js..

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu that are created on the fly by calling a JSON request.
My question is, how to build a menu like this:

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div>
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
            <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

pulling the data from a external JSON file (navigation.json) like this:

```
{
  menu: [
    {
      name: "Menu 1",
      sub: [
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 1"
        },
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 2"
        },
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Menu 2",
      sub: [
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 1"
        },
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 2"
        },
        {
           name: "Sub Menu 2"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

or I should build a another JSON structure to build that menu?
Thanks in advance!

By the way the structure of the Models are like this:

[image]

Comment: It's completly doable. I've put together an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bSr4P/  but I don't have the time to go through the code and provide any detailed explanation. I'll try to expand on this tomorrow if there won't be any answers.

Comment: @pawel woow! thanks man I really appreciate this! i copied ur code and try to edit but when i add event on one model both model was changing..